# Subquery return always single record

Tags: mysql

I am try to merge the query 1 is sub query of query 2 in 3. But it will return always single record.
Below is my Query,

```
1.SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(friend_id, LENGTH(friend_id)-2),'["','') AS friend_id FROM `friends_list` WHERE login_userid=90 

Output :
friend_id   
32,44

2.SELECT id, CONCAT(firstname," ",lastname) AS username FROM register WHERE id IN(32,44)

Output :
id  username    
32  Suresh M
44  Senthil Kumar
```

**Sample code,**

```
3.SELECT t1.id, CONCAT(t1.firstname," ",t1.lastname) AS username 
FROM register AS t1 
INNER JOIN friends_list AS t2 ON t1.id=t2.login_userid
WHERE t1.id IN( SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(friend_id, LENGTH(friend_id)-2),'["','') AS friend_id FROM `friends_list` WHERE login_userid=90 )

Output :
id  username    
32  Suresh M
```

*I want to the result,*

```
id  username    
32  Suresh M
44  Senthil Kumar
```

Please Correct my bad query(3rd).

Comment: Sorry Now i am edit my question.

Comment: Same result. It return one record.

Comment: Now i am edit my question.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove your inner join condition

```
SELECT t1.id, CONCAT(t1.firstname," ",t1.lastname) AS username 
    FROM register AS t1 
    WHERE t1.id IN( SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(friend_id,      LENGTH(friend_id)-2),'["','') AS friend_id FROM `friends_list` WHERE login_userid=90 )
```

Comment: It will return single row  32  Suresh M

Comment: ok @RamaLingam .. can u please tell me how many row select query inside IN condition is returning...  SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(friend_id,      LENGTH(friend_id)-2),'["','') AS friend_id FROM `friends_list` WHERE login_userid=90

Comment: It's only One Row running. Output :
friend_id   
32,44 So It's return a single record..?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(firstname," ",lastname) AS username 
FROM register 
WHERE id IN( SELECT (select TRIM(BOTH '["' from (select TRIM(BOTH '"]' from friend_id)))) as friend_id  FROM `friends_list` WHERE login_userid=90 )
```

Comment: It will return single row  32  Suresh M

Comment: why you need REPLACE & LEFT function on friend_id column ?? How your data stored in friend_id column ??

Comment: friend_id :  ["32,44"]

Comment: Again  
It will return single row 32 Suresh M

Answer (score 1):

This should work foy you @RamaLingam

Try this without using INNER JOIN,

```
SELECT t1.id
    , CONCAT(t1.firstname, " ", t1.lastname) AS username
    FROM register t1
    WHERE t1.id IN (
        SELECT CAST(REPLACE(LEFT(t2.friend_id, LENGTH(t2.friend_id)-2),'["','') AS UNSIGNED)
            FROM friend_list t2
            WHERE t2.login_userid = 90
    )
```

Comment: Mysql Error : syntax to use near 'AS UNSIGNED)

Comment: Mysql Error :  syntax to use near 'friend_id)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this one:

```
SELECT R.id
    , CONCAT(R.firstname, " ", R.lastname) AS username
    FROM register R
    WHERE R.id IN (
        SELECT CAST(REPLACE(LEFT(F.friend_id, LENGTH(F.friend_id)-2) ,'["' ,'') AS UNSIGNED)
            FROM friend_list F
            WHERE F.login_userid = 90
    )
```

Comment: Error: syntax to use near ')
            FROM friend_list F
            WHERE F.login_userid = 90
    )

Comment: Now it's run After add the  -2),'["',''). It's also return a single row.

Comment: Please try again. I forgot some codes from your question

Comment: Can you show me the result of these queries: `SELECT * FROM friend_list` and `SELECT * FROM register`